# decode uiwebview string

Tags: iphone, objective-c

i have a uiwebview. when i read string (from ) from this uiwebview i encodes come characters like #. how can i decode?

for example it gives %23test instead of #test. i need #test

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding: method of NSString:

```
NSString *encoded = @"%23test";
NSString *decoded = [encoded stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Comment: hi aBitObvious, it has problems while getting % char. it gives "%58'den ysnky'ye tepki" as "X'den ysnky'ye tepki". how can i solve? thanks.    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4338123/decoding-problem-uiwebview

Comment: What string are you expecting back?

Comment: my string is  "%58'den ysnky'ye tepki". i would like to write is as <a href=''></a> and when clicked i want to get it back.

Comment: Before putting the string into the html, encode it using `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding`.  For the `href`, use double quotes instead of single quote to delimit the url: `NSString *html = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<a href=\"%@\">Click This</a>", encodedString];`.

Comment: oohh, right. i was missing that single quote deliminating the string. thanks again.