# decoding problem uiwebview

Tags: iphone, uiwebview, decoding

i am using uiwebview in my application. there are some links when user clicks a http search starts. it works fine but i have problems while getting "%58 den ysnky'ye tepki" it is given as "X'den ysnky'ye tepki". it has problems with % char.

identifier:%58'den%20ysnky'ye%20tepki

decoded identifier:X'den ysnky'ye tepki

i am using stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding to decode the string like that;

NSLog(@"identifier:%@", identifier);
identifier = [identifier stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"decoded identifier:%@", identifier);

how can i get the correct string?
thanks...

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your string may not be encoded properly in the first place. %58 is the correct encoding for the letter “X” (see this [ASCII table](http://www.hobbyprojects.com/ascii-table/images/ascii-table1.gif)). As far as I can tell, therefore, the decode is behaving properly.

What are you expecting?

Comment: ok. my string is  "%58'den ysnky'ye tepki". how can write it to uiwebview as a <a href=''></a> link and get back properly? thanks.

Comment: You'll want something like this: <a href="%2558%27den+ysnky%27ye+tepki"></a> - Google up URL encoding to see how I arrived to that